# postgresql how to search within a field from a search term with and without a period

Tags: postgresql

Users enter a search term into an application and I look in a specific field for it. They don't want to get erroneous matches, ie if the search term is 'trump' they don't want to find 'trumpet' in the results. So I made sure that there was a space on either side of the search term like so: SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE description ~* ' trump '. That works fine, but now they want to be able to find results at the end of a sentence, ie trump. I could just include the search term with a period, but the next thing they will want is additional punctuation ie !, ?, so my question is, is there an elegant way to do this kind of a search, or is adding in all possibilities using an OR statement the only option?

Comment: Sounds like you need to be using regex instead of like. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example would look like this:

```
WHERE description ~* ' trump[.?! ]'
```

If you want to search for some additional characters (ie.@) just add them inside the brackets.
Like Joe suggested you might want to have a look at regex pattern matching.

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming that if you wanted you could use the same technique in front of the search term. For instance if I wanted to be able to search for results that were at the beginning of a sentence and therefore had no preceding space I could use WHERE description ~* '[ ]trump[.?! ]'